# Access JavaScript array object in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a `JSON` data about 150 users, i have convert that into `java script array`, now what i want it to pass this array to PHP, So that i can perform further operations on this array.

```
var JSONString = '[{'user_id' : "1", "user_name" : "abc", "email":"abc@gmail.com"}, {"user_id":"2", "user_name":"abc", "email":"abc2@gmail.com"}]'

var JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSONString);

 for (var key in JSONObject) {
    if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(JSONObject[key]["user_id"] + ", " + JSONObject[key]["user_name"]);
    }
  }
```

now what i need it to pass this array to PHP array variable , that will loop through and perform further operation.
i have seen some solution that display it on html with JavaScript, but i don't need that. i need this array object in php array variable.

Comment: just make a request to a php page that will handle the data. You could also do this with ajax so the page doesn't have to be reloaded

Comment: You can encode the array as JSON and pass it to PHP (using AJAX) with a POST reuqest and decode it.

Comment: @Unex it is on the same page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing JSON string in JavaScript, pass it directly to PHP and use 
PHP function

`json_decode($json, true)`

it will give you data in array format.

Comment: that is a static JSON data, not coming from any database.

Comment: it doesn't matter where it come from, this should work :o

Comment: @PravinS but that is what I am asking for , `Pass it directly to PHP1`

Comment: @MTaqi: how was you going to pass the string you where generating after parsing it in javascript?